# Hide console's user input after return/new line

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, stdout, readline

What I'd like to do is hiding/erasing all users **input** from a nodejs console app once **entered**, so that when the user **inserts** some text and then types enter, he won't be able to read what he just **entered** in the console anymore (so basically remove the line right after it's been **entered**).

This should be pretty simple to achieve but I have no idea how to do it =).

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
Let's say we have this code:

```
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
 })

rl.question('How ya doin?\n', input => {
    console.log('seems like you\'r doing ' + input.toString())  
})
```

- The app prompts a question
- The user answers "Fine" (This line shouldn't be there anymore after the user presses enter)
- The program says "seems like .... Fine"

[image: Output]

Comment: Have you tried this [How to clear console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006988/node-js-on-windows-how-to-clear-console) ?

Comment: I don't want to clear the console. I want to clear the user input only (not the program output)

Comment: Honestly not clear to me what exactly you want to do. Maybe try to explain with example?

Comment: @LEQADA question edited with example

Comment: Like this `process.stdout.write('\033[1A seems like you\'r doing ' + input.toString());` ?

Comment: yes sir, this answers my question

Comment: @TusharGupta I believe the duplicate target is wrong. There is indeed a difference in this question and the one you linked. This one here, wants to clear console *input*, not everything in it.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier re-opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Bash HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)

> Move the cursor up N lines:
>
> `\033[<N>A`

To overwrite user's 1 line input with your output you should move 1 line up and print your output. It will look like this:

```
console.log('\033[1A' + 'seems like you\'r doing ' + input.toString());
```

**UPDATE:**
Found a nice answer :)

[How do you edit existing text (and move the cursor around) in the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10830168/980828)

Comment: It doesn't effect anything to security? i think this way just ANSI color way..

Answer (score 8):

Looks like readline can already handle this for you..

```
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
 })

rl.question('How ya doin?\n', input => {
    readline.moveCursor(process.stdout, 0,-1)
    console.log('seems like you\'r doing ' + input.toString())  
})
```

Comment: RTM here -> https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_movecursor_stream_dx_dy