# Ansi escape sequences in chrome web console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

Wondering if chrome `console.log` allows you to go back and rewrite existing console.log output, [like you can do in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585683/how-do-you-edit-existing-text-and-move-the-cursor-around-in-the-terminal/10830168#10830168). I know you can do colors in the chrome console, but not sure about editing existing text. Would like to try adding a progress bar such as:

[image]

I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: Once output is evaluated and written to the console, you can't change it. However, you [can style it with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console) (which you might be able to hack to allow that behaviour).

Comment: FYI, latest version of Chrome (as mine Version 71.0.3578.98) support ansi color in console natively, so you won't get ansi escape code but the colored text.

Comment: Since Chrome 69, basic ansi escape codes are supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `console.clear` ([chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#clear), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear)) in a loop. This works as long as you have ‘preserve log’ turned off. It flickers a bit for me in Chrome’s console, but such is life (it's actually great in Firefox).

```js
delay=t=>new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve,t));

// the stack snippets console emulator doesn't seem
// to work if the very first call is clear.
console.log();

(async()=>{
  for(i=0;i<25;i++){
    console.clear();
    console.log('*'.repeat(i));
    await delay(100);
  }
})()
```