# Remove empty line from console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

The code is

```
console.log(process.argv[2]);
```

I get the following in console

```
node task.js ABC
'ABC'
<empty line>
```

Or without parameters (code is commented)

```
node task.js
<empty line>
```

How can i remove it?

EDIT: changed console.out to console.log

Comment: What is `console.out`? You are more than likely seeing that line because the function `console.out` returns *undefined* and the console will always output the return of whatever you typed in.

Comment: Whoops, i meant `console.log`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585683/how-do-you-edit-existing-text-and-move-the-cursor-around-in-the-terminal
Or if you need 1 line up process.stdout.write('\033[1A');

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:
`process.stdout.write("test")`
It will display your output directly to stdout, so It will not return empty line.

Comment: Won't help with no parameters case

Comment: @Nodedoesntwork In your case, you may try: `process.stdout.write(process.argv[2]);`

Comment: But if i don't have any parameters then `process.stdout.write(process.argv[2]);` will just return an error

Answer (score 0):

[How do you edit existing text (and move the cursor around) in the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585683/how-do-you-edit-existing-text-and-move-the-cursor-around-in-the-terminal)

Or if you need 1 line up

```
process.stdout.write('\033[1A');
```